# Why is there a redirect when retrieving a message from the Gmail API?

Tags: go, gmail, gmail-api

I attempted to retrieve an email using the Gmail API using Go. The Go client followed the redirects but stopped after reaching its limit:

> Get "https://www.google.com/sorry/index?continue=https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/186fcaba0de2c103%3Falt%3Djson%26format%3Dmetadata%26prettyPrint%3Dfalse&q=EhQ0WJdTGNi_5J4ZIjDuikp4BXiPLIs8CUe1LwNSe7C1o4C4rcYk2_W7gKUxVgXMh-MXORDYLkM4PRRenpjyAmRy": stopped after 10 redirects

It seems strange that fetching an email with an ID given by the Gmail API (via `users.history.list`) would result in redirects, especially more than 10. Why would `users.messages.get` employ any redirects? What does this signify? Is there any way to counteract it?

Comment: Do you have a sample code on how are you calling it?

Comment: It looks like I was experiencing the same problem as https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/159368649#comment45.